# Invalid use of group operation in mysql while using group by

Tags: mysql

```
 select a.col_name1,max(b.col_name2) from table_a , table_b b where
 a.candidate_id = 900 and a.col_name1 = b.col_name1 and a.col_name2=
  302885 group by b.candidate_id;
```

This is query is working fine for me

But when i use max(b.col_name2) it is giving this error `1111 invalid use of group function`.

```
select a.col_name1,max(b.col_name2) from table_a , table_b b where
a.candidate_id = 900 and a.col_name1 = b.col_name1 and a.col_name2=
max(b.col_name2)group by b.candidate_id;
```

How i can use `max(b.col_name2)` value

Please help me.Thanks in advance..

Comment: just to look better with colors your code :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   select a.col_name1,max(b.col_name2) 
   from table_a , table_b b 
   where a.candidate_id = 900 
   and a.col_name1 = b.col_name1 
   group by b.candidate_id 
   having a.col_name2= max(b.col_name2)
```

or

```
   select a.col_name1,max(b.col_name2) 
   from table_a , table_b b 
   where a.candidate_id = 900 
   and a.col_name1 = b.col_name1 
   and  a.col_name2 in ( select max(col_name2) from table_b)
   group by b.candidate_id
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Group By you need to specify the group's where clause in the Having clause:

```
select a.col_name1,
  max(b.col_name2) 
from table_a , table_b b 
where a.candidate_id = 900 and 
  a.col_name1 = b.col_name1 
group by b.candidate_id
having a.col_name2 = max(b.col_name2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because your query *runs* doesn't mean it "works well.".

Mysql has some weird grouping functionality.

Try this:

```
select
  a.col_name1,
  max(b.col_name2)
from table_a
join table_b b
  on a.col_name1 = b.col_name1
where a.candidate_id = 900
and a.col_name1 = b.col_name1
and a.col_name2 = 302885
group by a.col_name1;
```

Corrected/improved:

- formatting
- join syntax
- group by columns

Answer (score 0):

Also, always use explicit JOIN syntax...

```
SELECT a.col_name1
     , MAX(b.col_name2) 
  FROM table_a a
  JOIN table_b b 
    ON b.col_name1 = a.col_name1 
 WHERE a.candidate_id = 900 
 GROUP 
    BY b.candidate_id
HAVING a.col_name2 = MAX(b.col_name2);
```